# What was the point of Grigor Andolov's story at the end of s03e09 of Billions?

Tags: billions

One of the interesting moments in *Billions* was the end sequence of season 3 episode 9. John Malkovich's character (Grigor Andolov) started to tell a story, ostensibly a memory from his own past. The thing is, the story was completely unrelated to what they were talking about at the moment. What's more, it didn't even have an ending. All in all, I enjoyed watching it, but couldn't make much sense of it.